# Using OpenGL ES 2.0 with iOS, how do I draw a cylinder between two points?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am given two `GLKVector3`'s representing the start and end points of the cylinder. Using these points and the radius, I need to build and render a cylinder. I can build a cylinder with the correct distance between the points but in a fixed direction (currently always in the y (0, 1, 0) up direction). I am not sure what kind of calculations I need to make to get the cylinder on the correct plane between the two points so that a line would run through the two end points. I am thinking there is some sort of calculations I can apply as I create my vertex data with the direction vector, or angle, that will create the cylinder pointing the correct direction. Does anyone have an algorithm, or know of one, that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this awesome [article](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/opengl.c); it's dated but after adapting the algorithm, it works like a charm.  One tip, OpenGL ES 2.0 only supports triangles so instead of using GL_QUAD_STRIP as the method does, use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP instead and the result is identical. The [site](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) also contains a bunch of other useful information regarding OpenGL geometries.

See code below for solution. Self represents the mesh and contains the vertices, indices, and such.

```
- (instancetype)initWithOriginRadius:(CGFloat)originRadius
                   atOriginPoint:(GLKVector3)originPoint
                    andEndRadius:(CGFloat)endRadius
                      atEndPoint:(GLKVector3)endPoint
                   withPrecision:(NSInteger)precision
                        andColor:(GLKVector4)color
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    // normal pointing from origin point to end point
    GLKVector3 normal = GLKVector3Make(originPoint.x - endPoint.x,
                                       originPoint.y - endPoint.y,
                                       originPoint.z - endPoint.z);

    // create two perpendicular vectors - perp and q
    GLKVector3 perp = normal;
    if (normal.x == 0 && normal.z == 0) {
        perp.x += 1;
    } else {
        perp.y += 1;
    }

    // cross product
    GLKVector3 q = GLKVector3CrossProduct(perp, normal);
    perp = GLKVector3CrossProduct(normal, q);

    // normalize vectors
    perp = GLKVector3Normalize(perp);
    q = GLKVector3Normalize(q);

    // calculate vertices
    CGFloat twoPi = 2 * PI;        
    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < precision + 1; i++) {
        CGFloat theta = ((CGFloat) i) / precision * twoPi; // go around circle and get points

        // normals
        normal.x = cosf(theta) * perp.x + sinf(theta) * q.x;
        normal.y = cosf(theta) * perp.y + sinf(theta) * q.y;
        normal.z = cosf(theta) * perp.z + sinf(theta) * q.z;

        AGLKMeshVertex meshVertex;
        AGLKMeshVertexDynamic colorVertex;

        // top vertex
        meshVertex.position.x = endPoint.x + endRadius * normal.x;
        meshVertex.position.y = endPoint.y + endRadius * normal.y;
        meshVertex.position.z = endPoint.z + endRadius * normal.z;
        meshVertex.normal = normal;
        meshVertex.originalColor = color;

        // append vertex
        [self appendVertex:meshVertex];

        // append color vertex
        colorVertex.colors = color;
        [self appendColorVertex:colorVertex];

        // append index
        [self appendIndex:index++];

        // bottom vertex
        meshVertex.position.x = originPoint.x + originRadius * normal.x;
        meshVertex.position.y = originPoint.y + originRadius * normal.y;
        meshVertex.position.z = originPoint.z + originRadius * normal.z;
        meshVertex.normal = normal;
        meshVertex.originalColor = color;

        // append vertex
        [self appendVertex:meshVertex];

        // append color vertex
        [self appendColorVertex:colorVertex];

        // append index
        [self appendIndex:index++];
    }

    // draw command
    [self appendCommand:GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP firstIndex:0 numberOfIndices:self.numberOfIndices materialName:@""];
}

return self;
}
```

Comment: I did not, but I can certainly help if you post a question.

Comment: I could really do with an example of a cylinders for OpenGL 2.0  I have got a cube and a sphere working

Comment: Take a look at the code above, it should give you a good start.

Comment: @kschins What is AGLKMeshVertex and AGLKMeshVertexDynamic in above code? Asking because it gives me error on above 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing more than one of these cylinders? Or ever drawing it in a different position? If so, using the algorithm from the awesome article is a not-so-awesome idea. Every time you upload geometry data to the GPU, you incur a performance cost.

A better approach is to calculate the geometry for a single basic cylinder once — say, one with unit radius and height — and [stuff that vertex data into a VBO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW6). Then, when you draw, use a model-to-world transformation matrix to scale (independently in radius and length if needed) and rotate the cylinder into place. This way, the only new data that gets sent to the GPU with each draw call is a 4x4 matrix instead of all the vertex data for whatever polycount of cylinder you're drawing.

Comment: I may have to draw an arbitrary amount but generally just one. Its position can be anywhere. Currently, I'm generating the vertex data and storing it in a VBO. The performance is fine, and the number of vertices generated is fairly small at this point with the "resolution" I'm using for the number of points around the circle.