# iOS: transforming a view into cylindrical shape

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

With Quartz 2D we can transform our views on the `x`, `y`and `z` axis.

In some cases we could even make them look 3D by changing the values of the matrixes.

I was wondering if it could be possible to transform a view into a cylinder shape like in the following picture?

[image]

Please ignore the top part of the cylinder. I am more curious to know whether it would be possible warping an `UIView` around like the side of the cylinder as in the image.

Is that possible only making use of Quartz 2D, layers and transformations (not OpenGL)? If not, is it possible to at least draw it in `CGContext` to make a view appear like so?

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can't do this with a transform. What you could do is create your UIView off-screen, get the context for the view, get an image from that, and then map the image to a new image, using a non-linear mapping.

So:

1. Create an image context with UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()
2. Render the view there, with view.layer.renderInContext()
3. Get an image of the result with CGBitmapContextCreateImage()
4. Write a mapping function that takes the x/y screen coordinates and maps them to coordinates on the cylinder.
5. Create a new image the size of the screen view, and call the mapping
   function to copy pixels from the source to the destination.
6. Draw the destination bitmap to the screen.

None of these steps is particularly-difficult, and you might come up with various ways to simplify. For example, you can just render strips of the original view, offsetting the Y coordinate based on the coordinates of a circle, if you are okay with not doing perspective transformations.

If you want the view to actually be interactive, then you'd need to do the transform in the opposite direction when handling touch events.

Comment: It sounds promising. I will try it; if at the meanwhile something happens to come to your mind, please feel free to add. Happy holidays.

Comment: I'll edit and add something to my response, but briefly - you want a function that takes screen (x,y) coordinates, and maps them to your view, distorting them along the way. The simple version of that would be something like x = x and y = y + sqrt(r^2-x^2)

Comment: I would like to award the bounty to you, because your answer seems to carry some weight. I hope that you could still edit and add something to your response as said, even after the bounty will have been awarded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't bend a view using a transform.

The transform can only manipulate the four corners of the view so no matter what you do it will still be a plane.

Comment: As far as I know. Doing that kind of transform in Core Graphics is more or less as complicated as drawing a cylinder using OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this goes beyond Quartz2D... You could try adding SceneKit.

- Obtain the view's image via UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(), view.layer.renderInContext(), CGBitmapContextCreateImage().
- Create a SCNMaterial with the diffuse property set to the image of your view
- Create an SCNCylinder and apply the material to it.
- Add the cylinder to an SCNScene.
- Create an SCNView and set its scene.
- Add the SCNView to your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Reference : [Using OpenGL ES 2.0 with iOS, how do I draw a cylinder between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411066/using-opengl-es-2-0-with-ios-how-do-i-draw-a-cylinder-between-two-points)

I have also used the same code for one of my project:

Check this one where it is mentioned to draw [cone shape](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/opengl.c); it's dated but after adapting the algorithm, it works.

See code below for solution. Self represents the mesh and contains the vertices, indices, and such.

```
- (instancetype)initWithOriginRadius:(CGFloat)originRadius
                   atOriginPoint:(GLKVector3)originPoint
                    andEndRadius:(CGFloat)endRadius
                      atEndPoint:(GLKVector3)endPoint
                   withPrecision:(NSInteger)precision
                        andColor:(GLKVector4)color
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    // normal pointing from origin point to end point
    GLKVector3 normal = GLKVector3Make(originPoint.x - endPoint.x,
                                       originPoint.y - endPoint.y,
                                       originPoint.z - endPoint.z);

    // create two perpendicular vectors - perp and q
    GLKVector3 perp = normal;
    if (normal.x == 0 && normal.z == 0) {
        perp.x += 1;
    } else {
        perp.y += 1;
    }

    // cross product
    GLKVector3 q = GLKVector3CrossProduct(perp, normal);
    perp = GLKVector3CrossProduct(normal, q);

    // normalize vectors
    perp = GLKVector3Normalize(perp);
    q = GLKVector3Normalize(q);

    // calculate vertices
    CGFloat twoPi = 2 * PI;        
    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < precision + 1; i++) {
        CGFloat theta = ((CGFloat) i) / precision * twoPi; // go around circle and get points

        // normals
        normal.x = cosf(theta) * perp.x + sinf(theta) * q.x;
        normal.y = cosf(theta) * perp.y + sinf(theta) * q.y;
        normal.z = cosf(theta) * perp.z + sinf(theta) * q.z;

        AGLKMeshVertex meshVertex;
        AGLKMeshVertexDynamic colorVertex;

        // top vertex
        meshVertex.position.x = endPoint.x + endRadius * normal.x;
        meshVertex.position.y = endPoint.y + endRadius * normal.y;
        meshVertex.position.z = endPoint.z + endRadius * normal.z;
        meshVertex.normal = normal;
        meshVertex.originalColor = color;

        // append vertex
        [self appendVertex:meshVertex];

        // append color vertex
        colorVertex.colors = color;
        [self appendColorVertex:colorVertex];

        // append index
        [self appendIndex:index++];

        // bottom vertex
        meshVertex.position.x = originPoint.x + originRadius * normal.x;
        meshVertex.position.y = originPoint.y + originRadius * normal.y;
        meshVertex.position.z = originPoint.z + originRadius * normal.z;
        meshVertex.normal = normal;
        meshVertex.originalColor = color;

        // append vertex
        [self appendVertex:meshVertex];

        // append color vertex
        [self appendColorVertex:colorVertex];

        // append index
        [self appendIndex:index++];
    }

    // draw command
    [self appendCommand:GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP firstIndex:0 numberOfIndices:self.numberOfIndices materialName:@""];
}

return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the code. I will go ahead and try it. Happy holidays.

Comment: Sorry, but not having that project now, otherwise I would have shared. It was done in my previous organization.

Comment: This would be tough to translate this to code, but here is the mathematical solution, http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/